# Easily debug Ionic 2 apps

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm new to ionic and I have an error coming and going during the build

```
build dev failed: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
```

I say come and go because I have no clue where it comes from, and it seems to appear sometime and sometime not for the same code base.

It is also an understatement to say that this error message does not help, so I'm wondering. Where should I look at to try to understand where it wants to see this index of an undefined item ?

Thanks!

Comment: include relevant codes

Comment: That's the thing, right, I don't know what is the relevant code, because I don't know where in my app I have this crash.

Comment: You cant expect others to guess the issue by just the message. What you could do would be, delete ``node_modules``,``.tmp`` and ``www`` folders and try ``npm install`` on root folder. Then try ``ionic serve``.

Comment: That is exactly my point. It turns out that I had to delete the node_modules/firebase/firebase.d.ts because some things were duplicately defined between angularfire2 and firebase. But to find that it was a game of guessing and searching google with very little clue. My stack overflow question here would be "is there a file somewhere that could have told me that I had an issue with firebase" ? like a build fail log file that would have this information?

Comment: This issue has already been discussed in detail at: [FireBase CLI issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1713) and [App-scripts](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/issues/544).  It seems there is some version compatibility between both and it has been fixed in angularfire2 2.0.0-beta.6 and firebase 3.6.4

Comment: Look guys, I already explained in the post and in my previous comments. I'm not looking for a solution to this very problem...  I found it already. I'm looking for a way to understand these kind of problem, to find which part of the program makes the build break. If there is nothing like that, fine, but that's kind of disappointing

Answer (score 1):

I do this personally and **this isn't the best answer** but you could change the node modules logger.js to display the full stack.

I guess ionic team just didn't expect you would encounter these errors or more likely idealistically you shouldn't encounter them or fix them. I think this was their idea.

You may go to .\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\logger\logger.js

On this here line:

```
 var failedMsg = this.scope + " failed";
                if (err.message) {
                    failedMsg += ": " + err.message;
                }
```

Change it to this:

```
  var failedMsg = this.scope + " failed. Stack: " + err.stack;
                if (err.message) {
                    failedMsg += ": " + err.message;
                }
```

Hope someone could suggest a cleaner solution.

Or run like this  `npm run ionic:build --debug`

Comment: Thanks! you have understood what I was looking for, I will try that. I don't tick your answer as per your line, there might be more answers so I let the thing open, but real big thanks to you